# Get DB column names from annotated bean in java

Tags: java, annotations, spring-annotations

In the below bean where the annotation is mapped to a DB column , how to get the values in a string.

I need all values like below

"TY_CD,ACTION_CD,ID"

```
public class SampleBO implements SQLData{

    @DbColumnMap(columnName = "TY_CD")
    private String typeCode;

    @DbColumnMap(columnName = "ACTION_CD")
    private String actionCd;

    @DbColumnMap(columnName = "ID")
    private String id;
}
```

Comment: You have to write an annotation parser.

Comment: Reflection would work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get list of the class' fields

```
SampleBO.class.getFields()
```

(An array of Field is returned) and go through the array to check whether it has the annotation. See [the example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html) If the annotation present you can get value of the annotation's columnName.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example. Notice that I searched for the "name" of a JPA "column" annotation in an "Address" class here:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Field[] fields = Address.class.getDeclaredFields();
     for (Field field : fields) {
        Column col = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if (col != null) {
            System.out.println(col.name() + "!");
        }
     }
 }
```